# What creates a Web.config appSettings entry?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration, web-config

I am fairly green at ASP.NET coding, even though I have done very basic tasks for a while.

Recently, I have been assigned our company's website, so I am learning more of the details.

I downloaded the project from Source Safe, and I am making changes in the code.

A co-worker and I were looking at the `Web.config` file, and noticed this under the `<configuration>` section:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="HR_EMAIL" value="myEmailAddress@work.com"/>
  <add key="APP_MODE" value="TEST"/>
  <!-- PROD is the production value for ssl pages -->
  <add key="HR_EMAIL_SITE_A" value="myEmailAddress@work.com"/>
  <add key="HR_EMAIL_SITE_B" value="myEmailAddress@work.com"/>
</appSettings>
```

where `myEmailAddress@work.com` used to list my actual email address.

My co-worker said, "Oh, you've changed it and removed my email address."

Uh, no I have not! I could care less if these people email me!

I'm guessing something configured on my local machine (maybe in `machine.config`) went in and updated these values whenever I rebuilt the project.

I have used a walkthrough recently published by Microsoft ([Walkthrough: Creating a Web Site with Membership and User Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)), but it was in a different project.

What changed these values? Surely I did not do this in my sleep!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely find that due to differences in enviroments, in most cases you don't deploy a web.config from enviroment to enviroment. You wouldn't want test settings, like connection strings, emails, etc getting propigated to production.

When you're likely finiding is the config in VSS is a local testing copy and the production copy has different values.

Comment: Difficult to understand what you said, but I ***think*** this is what happened.

Comment: Your web.config file contains your settings for the project. If you deploy a config file from local to DEV, QA or PROD you're likely going to over-write what should be there for that enviroment. This is why (in most cases) the config files are NEVER migrated from enviroment to enviroment. There are ways to deal with this such as abstracting the config settings out to a directory above the root of the website, like  <appSettings file="..\AppSettings.config"/>. What you'll find when doing development is that what you check in to source control isn't always what you want to be deployed to PROD.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that someone committed these values to source control.

You got the latest value - possibly your workmate has not updated this file in a while.

Take a look at the file history in Source Safe to see what happened with this value.

Answer (score 1):

section, as the name suggests, is specific to application to store custom settings. Before ASP .NET 2, this section was used to store things like connection string used by the web application.

In you case, I am guessing that, you have an admin site/system that is writing out your email adress to app.config.

I have seen another scenario, where setting will be updated by the build/release script.

Comment: You would not happen to know how I could go about confirming this, would you?